# How to convert an array into list

Tags: arrays, list, prolog

I am working on a scenario in prolog (eclipseCLP), where I have an array of elements in one variable. Now to continue working on the solution, I need to have this "array" of elements converted into "list" form.

Example:

```
MyArray = [](1,2,3)
```

Now this MyArray should be converted into a list as below:

```
MyList = [1,2,3].
```

Basically convert an array to list. Can this be done in prolog?

Answer (score 0):

With the [univ operator](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=%28%3D..%29/2) `=../2`:

```
array2list(A, L) :-
    A =.. [_|L].
```